# How to use the SceneBuilder with IntelliJ on Mac

Tags: java, macos, intellij-idea, javafx

I'm trying to use the SceneBuilder with IntelliJ on Mac. So I downloaded the .dmg file from there http://gluonhq.com/products/downloads/

Now I supplied the following path to the SceneBuilder in IntelliJ:

```
/Applications/SceneBuilder.app/Contents/MacOS/SceneBuilder
```

When I tried to open a `.fxml`, I get the error

```
Failed to start SceneBuilder:
/Applications/SceneBuilder.app/Contents/MacOS/SceneBuilder/Contents/MacOS/scenebuilder-launcher.sh
```

It seems like IntelliJ is looking for this sh-script but I have no clue where it is to be honest. I have looked over several webpages on the net but no one helped me actually...

So how do I fix my problem or how can use the scene builder in IntelliJ?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Look at the path it is trying to open.. I suggest you to convert your configured SceneBuilder path to:

```
/Applications/SceneBuilder.app/
```

---

**Edit:** Quick fix would be to download the old SceneBuilder 2 here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafxscenebuilder-1x-archive-2199384.html and extract its `sh` start script to the correct folder.

Comment: Same error... I tried this too before, but it seems like this script is not in the app I downloaded... although I have no clue why. Also you should remove the last slash in your suggestion...

Comment: @user2336315 Long term solution would be to file a bug report at IntelliJ, NetBeans did the same: https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=251308#c1

Answer (score 6):

I've solved the problem.

**1. First go to:**

Eclipse (Or IntelliJ) -> Preferences -> JavaFX -> Then type/choose "/Applications/SceneBuilder.app" -> Press Ok

**2. Then, go to:**

Applications -> Right click on SceneBuilder -> Click on "Show package contents" --> Contents -> MacOS -> Rename the file "SceneBuilder" as **"scenebuilder-launcher.sh"**

There you go!

Comment: if you don't want to modify the file name, you could also add a symlink: cd /Applications/SceneBuilder.app/Contents/MacOS && ln -s SceneBuilder scenebuilder-launcher.sh

Comment: My "Open in SceneBuilder" option still doesn't work, but the Scene Builder tab at the bottom, does! Wonder why...

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me.

Downloaded the .dmg for the Mac at http://gluonhq.com/open-source/scene-builder/

Install SceneBuilder which will then be located under Applications.

**In IntelliJ**

Ensured that the path was correct by going to the following:

IntelliJ IDEA -> Preferences -> Languages and Frameworks -> JavaFX

The value for "Path to SceneBuilder" should be /Applications/SceneBuilder.app

**As per Rilcy88**

Renamed SceneBuilder to scenebuilder-launcher.sh under Applications -> Contents -> MacOS.

In the project, I was able to right click on my .fxml file and selected "Open in Scenbuilder" with no problems.